# How to get a list of loaded EF4.0 properties of a disconnected object using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How do I use reflection to get a list of loaded properties of a disconnected EF object?

I can use

```
var targetProperty.GetValue(targetObject, null);
var isLoaded = ((System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd)(propertyValue)).IsLoaded;
```

but this only works for collection properties.  For single object property, it doesn't work well.  It will give message

> The ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.

The code I use is similar to the following

```
IEnumerable<object> q;

using(var context = new InfosContext())
{
  q = context.Person.Include("Father").Take(10).ToList();
}
foreach(var value in q)
{
  var sourceProperties = value.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
  var singleProperties = sourceProperties.Where(i => i.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName.StartsWith("TestProject.Models.Entities")).ToList();
  foreach(var i in singleProperties)
  {
     var propertyValue = i.GetValue(value, null);  // BOOM.  Exception here.
     if (propertyValue != null && ((System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd)(propertyValue)).IsLoaded) 
     {
     }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var i in singleProperties)
{
  var reference = value.GetType().GetProperty(i.Name + "Reference");
  var refValue = reference.GetValue(value, null);
  var isLoaded = ((System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference)(refValue)).IsLoaded;
  if(isLoaded)
  {
  }
}
```